# C++ GNU GCC with #define out & colliding

Tags: c++, gcc, macros, std, gnu

I am working with `Code::Blocks` and `C++ GNU GCC` and trying to port my `Visual Studio Project` to `GNU GCC`.
And while I am trying to compile I get stuck with my define macro from a `Defines.h` file:

```
#define out &
```

And when compiling I get this error:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before '=' token
```

On this line:

```
// Open for output.  Default for @c ofstream and fstream.
static const openmode out =     _S_out;
```

**In ios_base.h**

As I know, that file is a part of a `libstd` library. Can I disable it? If so, how can I do that?
My library doesn't requiring any `std c++`, just `c` library.

Comment: `out` should be placed before name of variable, not after it, hence the compilation error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main options:

1. Don't define a macro using the word `out`.
2. Declare the macro after you include all of your headers.

But seriously, a macro named `out` that becomes `&` is a pretty awful macro. It's going to make it difficult to understand the code very quickly.

Comment: I know, this library is really special, but just don't think about that.
But I haven't included the ios_base.h somewhere.
This library builds on MSVC++ and Android GCC 4.6. But I know that GCC 4.6 for Anroid doesn't include any STL. So I think I have to disable that here.

Comment: Imo, the stupid `min`, `max`, `near`, and `far` macros in Windows are just as bad, if not worse.

Comment: I took the second answer. I saw that Code::Blocks had a nice feature to see a header include tree when a got the error. Thank you for continue with my special weird library ;)